# Can Exchange 2010 Transport Agents be built and installed with .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server-2010

I'm trying to use .NET 4.0 to build a Exchange 2010 transport agent.
But I had to compile as x64 and .NET 3.5 for the install to work (used VS2013) otherwise I get an error: "This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded." when trying to install the agent.

.NET 3.5 was required by the two references

```
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Common

Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Transport
```

But according to [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728623.aspx) .NET 4.0 is supported on Exchange 2010

I've used [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877026%28EXCHG.140%29.aspx) guide to build the agent

I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229687/exchange-server-transport-agent-wont-load-built-by-a-newer-runtime) article but I can't get a .NET 4.0 version of the .dll to install

Answer (score 0):

In 2023 that Article states clearly that Exchange 2010 uses only .NET Framework 3.5 although it is possible to install .net FW 4.0 in parallel on such servers.

As the latest/newest versions of these 2 dlls **for Exchange 2010 (SP3, CU32)** are still built with .NET Framework 2.0 (which is included in .NET 3.5), by hard experience of mine it is **not** possible to build installable Exchange 2010 transport agents with .net Framework 4.0.

The highest I could go was .NET FW 3.5.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it can be built in Framework .NET 4.0.

what actually matters is the correct version number of the following files:

```
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Common
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Transport
```

PLEASE NOTE:

Whenever you update the Exchanger Server (E.g. Service Pack, Update Rollups) ther version of these two files might chance.

So, Microsoft Exchange Transport Service does not get up again